# Why are these check boxes not showing with the correct text colour in Inno Setup with skins?

Tags: inno-setup, skin

I am using a skin with my Inno Setup:

```
#define Skin "Amakrits.vsf"
```

I use the VCL Styles DLL for the skinning:

```
Source: {#InnoPath}\VclStylesinno.dll; DestDir: "{app}";
```

I have a custom page for application settings:

```
function AppSettings_CreatePage(PreviousPageId: Integer): Integer;
var
    Page: TWizardPage;
    iUserValue: Cardinal;
    strPath: String;
begin
    Page := CreateCustomPage(
        PreviousPageId,
        ExpandConstant('{cm:ApplicationPreferences}'),
        ExpandConstant('{cm:DefaultSettings}')
    );

    // lblInfo
    lblInfo := TLabel.Create(Page);
    with lblInfo do
    begin
        Parent := Page.Surface;
        Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:SpecifyDefaultSettings}');
        Left := ScaleX(8);
        Top := ScaleY(8);
        Width := ScaleX(387);
        Height := ScaleY(29);
    end;

    // chkRememberLastCong
    chkRememberLastCong := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
    with chkRememberLastCong do
    begin
        Parent := Page.Surface;
        Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:UserRememberCongregation}');
        Left := ScaleX(8);
        Top := ScaleY(32);
        Width := ScaleX(385);
        Height := ScaleY(25);
        TabOrder := 0;

        // Set default value (for when registry value does not exist)
        iUserValue := 1;
        // Get registry value
        RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM,
                     'Software\Community Talks\Public Talks\Preferences',
                     'ReuseCong', iUserValue);
        // Update option on page.
        Checked := iUserValue = 1;
    end;

    // chkDuplicates
    chkDuplicates := TCheckBox.Create(Page);
    with chkDuplicates do
    begin
        Parent := Page.Surface;
        Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:UserCheckDuplicates}');
        Left := ScaleX(8);
        Top := ScaleY(56);
        Width := ScaleX(393);
        Height := ScaleY(17);
        TabOrder := 1;

        // Set default value (for when registry value does not exist)
        iUserValue := 0;    // Default
        // Get registry value
        RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM,
                     'Software\Community Talks\Public Talks\Preferences',
                     'Duplicate', iUserValue);
        // Update option on page.
        Checked := iUserValue = 1;
    end;

    // lblDatabase
    lblDatabase := TLabel.Create(Page);
    with lblDatabase do
    begin
        Parent := Page.Surface;
        Caption := ExpandConstant('{cm:DatabaseLanguage}');
        Left := ScaleX(8);
        Top := ScaleY(112);
        Width := ScaleX(385);
        Height := ScaleY(13);
    end;

    // cbDatabase
    cbDatabase := TNewComboBox.Create(Page);
    with cbDatabase do
    begin
    #define DatabaseFile(Name, Text) \
        'Items.Add(''' + Text + ''');' + NewLine + \
        'if ActiveLanguage = ''' + Name + ''' then ItemIndex := Items.Count - 1;' + NewLine

        Parent := Page.Surface;
        Left := ScaleX(8);
        Top := ScaleY(128);
        Width := ScaleX(177);
        Height := ScaleY(21);
        Style := csDropDownList;
        TabOrder := 3;

        // Languages
        {#DatabaseFiles}
   
        // Get path where the program was last install
        strPath := GetPathInstalled('Public Talks');
  end;

  Result := Page.ID;
end;
```

What I don't understand is why the check boxes do not render with the correct text colour? See:

[image]

---

> Do standard checkboxes/radio buttons have an expected color?

Here are two standard windows in the installer which have checkboxes/radio controls by default, and they have white text as expected.

- Checkboxes

[image]

- Radios

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why the check boxes do not render with the correct text colour?

It is because you are using 'standard' Delphi components like `TCheckBox`, `TLabel`, etc.

Use Inno Setup 'New' components that supports custom drawing:

TCheckBox -> T**New**CheckBox

TLabel -> **TNewStaticText**

Code:

```
chkRememberLastCong: TNewCheckBox;
chkDuplicates: TNewCheckBox;
lblDatabase: TNewStaticText;
cbDatabase: TNewComboBox;
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing this now. Having looked at my data folder for my project I saw that I had a legacy Inno Form Designer (ISF) file from 2007 which was using the older controls. That was the boilerplate script that ended in my main script all that time back.

Comment: Question, in my script I use `TLabel` for the captions, like `lblDatabase` and `lblInfo`. But you are suggesting `TNewStaticText`?

Comment: Aside from my question in the preceding comment, I have tested this and it works. So I will mark as accepted. Thanks!